# Reading the csv file in an efficient manner in java

Tags: java, performance, csv

I have the below csv file which is comma delimited , now from this file  i need to read the value of the column der_id , which i have done , but please advise how can I achieve the same in java in a more optimized way through scanner or through any approach in java which is more optimized ine than this..

```
wert,der_tran,der_id,der_version,cvns_num,cvs_type
AB42126325,0,694698683,0,651626843,13002
AB42126326,0,694698686,0,651626846,13001
```

presently I am reading this in this format..

```
public class Parsingcsv {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Parsingcsv obj = new Parsingcsv();
        obj.run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String csvFile = "C:\\abc_2.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try 
            {
               br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
               while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] id = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("[der_id= " + id[2] + "]");

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }    
        System.out.println("#####################3");
    }

}
```

Comment: post this question in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting a line to extract id is inefficient, try this

```
String id = line.replaceAll(".*?,.*?,(.*?),.*", "$1");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can you also please advise in brief what this regular expression will do.

Comment: it says find the 3rd token (comma separated) in the input string and replace the whole input with it (actually return it)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use a library. There are recommendations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12410538/1269969)

Comment: so please advise how can i make my above program more optimized one.